# Creating a table for people in a column who reach a minimum assigned value?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I'm new to R and I'm struggling with a particular problem.
I have a data frame of people hailing from different locations, and I'm trying to create a table from that data of regions that have at least 3 people hailing from it.

I've created a table and sorted it in order of increasing numerical value

```
sort(table(GCBers$Location), decreasing = FALSE)
```

but now I'm stuck on how to only return locations that have at least 3 people hailing from it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want? We need to create a simple data set that resembles yours:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- sample(LETTERS[1:10], 50, replace=TRUE)
xtable <- sort(table(x), decreasing=FALSE)
xtable
# x
# F G C I A E H B J D 
# 2 2 3 4 5 6 6 7 7 8 
xtable[xtable > 2]
# x
# C I A E H B J D 
# 3 4 5 6 6 7 7 8
```